# What are Team Blocks, Team Platforms, Presserators, and how can I get them?

Tags: terraria

The 1.3.1 update for PC Terraria was just released, and with it a bunch of new items mostly related to wiring. Among these, the changelog mentions Team Blocks, Team Platforms, and a Presserator. What do these items do, and how can I obtain them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Team Blocks](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Team_Block), Team Platforms, and [Presserators](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Presserator) are sold by the Traveling Merchant. The Wiki currently doesn't have a page on Team Platforms, but I found the Traveling Merchant in-game and bought some.

Team Blocks and Team Platforms come in various colors corresponding to the different multiplayer team colors. They are always the color of a particular team, and don't seem to have any special effects to them, simply being normal platforms and blocks.

The Presserator is an accessory that causes you to automatically place Actuators at the same time as other blocks while it's equipped, as long as you have some in your inventory.